# Unexpected RxJS shareReplay Behavior with refCount: true

Tags: angular, rxjs

When using shareReplay with `refCount: true` I would expect it to unsubscribe from the source when there are no active subscriptions, but it seems to be hanging on to some other kind of reference? We encountered this while doing http requests which complete after emitting, but for the example I'm using `of()` which seems to do the same thing.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jdpxpe?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

The only difference between the two observables is one ends with a take(1). But in both cases their subscribers both **complete** and **unsubscribe**, and all the take operator is supposed to do is complete after the N emissions so it seems redundant but it does change the behavior.

[image]

But you can see that without the `take(1)` the badObservable still believes that it has a reference so it's not unsubscribing from the source and won't rerun the request.

It feels even stranger if you move the `take(1)` off the shared observable and pair it with the caller, since then the two multicasting observables are truly identical when defined, but you have to make sure to access the "good" one with `this.goodObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({` in order for the shared observable to properly unsubscribe/resubscribe from the original source request. But if ANYONE comes along and does `this.goodObservable.subscribe` suddenly the original shared observable is stuck for all future requests and it won't ever unsubscribe from the source (in our case will never make the http request again). But the important thing is that in both cases `this.goodObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe` and `this.goodObservable.subscribe` the subscriptions completes and claims to be [closed/unsubscribed](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription#properties)! So from the outside I can't see any discernable difference, anyone wondering "do I need a take(1) or to manually unsubscribe" would see that it's already completing/unsubscribing without anything extra and not realize that it's still required to add take(1) to not break the underlying observable.

**UPDATE:**

After digging around on github I found a number of issues around this:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5587

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6760

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5894

It looks like the behavior was changed at some point so it does not reset the completed observable which caused (and is apparently still causing some confusion). The correct way to get the expected shareReplay functionality with refCount true is to just use share:

```
    share({
      connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
      resetOnError: true,
      resetOnComplete: true,
      resetOnRefCountZero: true
    })
```

Which does work.

What I still don't really grasp yet is why take(1) somehow gets around this even for observables that complete after a single emission (like http requests). Is the take somehow unsubscribing and shutting it down before it realizes the source observable has technically also completed? At first I thought somehow take(1) was always causing a new replaySubject to be created with each subscription, but if you delay the http response and subscribe multiple times they will all share the same request.

Answer (score 2):

You are sharing a completed observable, because `of()` will emit once, synchronously, and will complete instantly. HTTP requests will do the same, just asynchronously.

When you share a completed observable, its result will be saved in the underlying Replay forever, as [said in docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/shareReplay#description):

> A successfully completed source will stay cached in the shareReplayed observable forever, but an errored source can be retried.

If you modify your example to use non-completed observable, you'll see that the result is actually shared and behaves as expected:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-s5ecqt?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: The sharing is what we're expecting. What we aren't expecting is setting `refCount: true` to have no effect. There seems to be no difference between your example and mine. Your  goodObservable still has a take(1) which is doing something to the shareReplay that's allowing the refCount:true to actually function, and it resubs to your emit10times. But without the take(1) the emit10times will never be reexecuted on further subscriptions to the badObservable even though nothing is subscribed to it.

Comment: Note that you can make them behave the same by setting `refCount: false` for the goodObservable, so now it will never unsubscribe from the underlying source even when it's refCount drops to 0 and behaves the same as the bad Observable. 
But without the take(1) the refCount just doesn't seem to do anything at all even when the new subscriptions are fully completing/unsubscribing. What would be keeping the actual reference counter from reaching 0?: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay#reference-counting